# javascript validate form when fields changing every time

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form with fields changing every time, but javascript function don't work.

What's the problem in my javascript code?

---

my form is made by code below:

```
<form name="Form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

    <? if (/*statement*/){ ?>
        <label>city </label><input type="text" name="city" />
    <?}?>

    <? if (/*statement*/){ ?>
        <label>color </label><input type="text" name="color" />
    <?}?>

    <? if (/*statement*/){ ?>
        <label>animal </label><input type="text" name="animal" />
    <?}?>

    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">submit</button>

</form>
```

---

and my javascript.js is like below

```
function validateForm() {

    var x = document.forms["Form"]["city"].value;
    var y = document.forms["Form"]["color"].value;
    var z = document.forms["Form"]["animal"].value;

    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("need city");
        return false;
    }
    if (y == null || y == "") {
        alert("need color");
        return false;
    }
    if (z == null || z == "") {
        alert("need animal");
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

- The javascript function works only if my form shows "city","color",and "animal" fields.
- The javascript function don't work in the other cases, for example: my form shows "color" and "animal", or only shows "animal", etc.

Comment: is your javascript wrapped in php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix is to check if the element exists before trying to access its value. Try the following:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["Form"]["city"];
    var y = document.forms["Form"]["color"];
    var z = document.forms["Form"]["animal"];

    if (x != null && x.value == "") {
        alert("need city");
        return false;
    }
    if (y != null && y.value == "") {
        alert("need color");
        return false;
    }
    if (z != null && z.value == "") {
        alert("need animal");
        return false;
    }

    return true; // if everything is valid
}
```

Comment: That's a easy way to do! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

since your fields generated dynamically you can not access element such as `<input type="text" name="city" />` if its not there so in general you need to go through all textboxes inside form.please see code below

```
    function validateForm() {
        alert("here");
        $('#Form input[type="text"]').each(function(){
        //your code here
        var data=""+$(this).val();
        if(data=="")
        {
            var name=$(this).attr("name");
            alert("Please Enter "+name);
        }

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check input's element is defined before you assigning the value in javascript, since its dynamically printing. For example

```
document.forms["Form"]["city"].value
```

In javascript, you have to use below code to check its defined

```
if(document.forms["Form"]["test"] !== undefined)
 alert(document.forms["Form"]["city"].value)
```

Or use jQuery code that was added by Atul

Answer (score 0):

You used template to generate HTML, so if the page did not show "city" means the "city" tag do not exist, and your JS code will crash in "var x" line, because document.forms["Form"]["city"] is UNDEFINED.

I suggest you modify your JS code like this:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["Form"]["city"];
    var y = document.forms["Form"]["color"];
    var z = document.forms["Form"]["animal"];

    if (x != undefined && x == "") {
        alert("need city");
        return false;
    }
    if (y != undefined && y == "") {
        alert("need color");
        return false;
    }
    if (z != undefined && z == "") {
        alert("need animal");
        return false;
    }
}
```

The field will be undefined, if you do not output it.